# Firebase custom authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to setup custom authentication with my firebase system, I am looking at this firebase [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens) one. I noticed with this approach you need to send the users credentials to your server:

However, I have implemented our system in a different way - where when the user enters their display name the credentials are posted to the server, the db will check whether these credentials are stored in the db and only if they are then the encrypted password shall be sent back to the java class where it will be stored in a string and decryted.

The password will then be compared with the password entered, if they are correct I want to generate the custom auth token with this method

```
mAuth.signInWithCustomToken(mCustomToken)
```

and then allow the user to login. So basically in short I want to create the custom auth token in my java class which is part of the application.

P.S I am using firebase realtime db as my db

Comment: Can you please clearly state your question?

Comment: Yes, the question needs some more clarity. Can you also look at this [Firebase Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020478/firebase-admin-java-sdk-in-a-standalone-program) and help me if possible?